# How would I color parts of my NSMutableAttributedString in a loop with new lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I have a function that appends data along with new line characters, up to a specified maximum. It then truncates the last new line character, and returns the result. However, I want to do this with NSMutableAttributedString so that each piece of data can be colored according to something.

Here's what I have...

```
- (NSString *)widgetNameAppendedWithNewLineForMaximum:(int)maximum
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

    int count = 0;
    if (maximum > 0) {
        for (Widget *widget in self.widgets) {
            if (count >= maximum) {
                break;
            }

            [result appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", widget.fullName]];

            count++;
        }
    }

    return [result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

However, I want each widget.fullName to be colored based on a certain set. Let's say we are returned an appropriate color via the following call...

```
[[ColorManager sharedManager] colorForWidgetFullName:widget.fullName];
```

How can I do the above with attributed string so that widget names can be colored differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSAttributedString *)widgetNameAppendedWithNewLineForMaximum:(int)maximum {
    NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

    NSString *separator = @"";
    int count = 0;
    for (Widget *widget in self.widgets) {
        if (count >= maximum) {
            break;
        }

        NSString *fullName = widget.fullName;
        UIColor *color = [[ColorManager sharedManager] colorForWidgetFullName:fullName];
        NSString *line = [separator stringByAppendingString:line];
        separator = @"\n";

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color };
        NSAttributedString *richLine = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:line
            attributes:attributes];
        [result appendAttributedString:richLine];
        count++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How can you trim the last newline character? There is no built in method for trimming on attributed strings it appears.

Comment: I don't trim it because I don't add it. I add a `\n` **before** each line except the first. Look at how I initialize, use, and update `separator`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you do add a `\n` at the end, you can remove it with `[result.mutableString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(result.mutableString-1, 1)]`.

Comment: Trim via using the range function